# How does virtual particle become real particle in Hawking radiation?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

I am new to black hole and general relativity and am just getting introduced to these concepts.

According to my understanding, virtual particle that forms because of quantum fluctuation becomes real particle because of gravitational effects that prolong the life of virtual particle. Is this correct understanding?

Comment: The virtual particle explanation is only an analogy and not to be taken seriously. See the linked question for what actually causes Hawking radiation.

Answer (score 1):

A pair of virtual particles are formed on the event horizon of a black hole--this is a particle anti-particle pair. These form all the time, but they usually just annihilate each other. However, if they form just on the black hole's event horizon, then one will be trapped in the gravitational field of the black hole, while the other can escape freely. Thus, to us, it appears that the black hole is emitting radiation--i.e., Hawking radiation.